# Data recovery from jQuery DatePicker does not work

Tags: jquery, datepicker

the Data recovery from jQuery DatePicker does not work. $dateDebut and $dateFin are empty.. I do not understand why. I recovered data from #from and #to but my 2 echo test doesn't work.

```js
<script>
  $(function() {

    

    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1d",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      dateFormat : '@',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      dateFormat : '@',
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
        var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
 
<label for="from">Du</label>
<input type="text" id="from" name="from">
<label for="to">Au</label>
<input type="text" id="to" name="to">

<?php
  $dateDebut = $_POST[‘from’] ;
  $dateFin = $_POST[‘to’] ;
  echo('La date est : ' . $dateDebut);
  echo($dateFin);
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your datepicker inputs in a `<form>` element? If so, is the method set to POST and the action set to the same page, and are you submitting the form? That's the only way the dates would populate in PHP is if the `<form>` pointed to the same page with POST, so the variables appeared in the server-side $_POST array; your PHP block runs before the rest of the script, so if you're not submitting the information via POST, there's no $_POST variables in your above posted script. That's a mouthful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrap your datepicker `<input>` elements in a `<form>`, and set the action to the same page, you can check the `$_POST` variable on the same page after submitting the form. Without submitting, PHP will have no way to obtain the variables. You could alternatively look into AJAX if you're attempting to use the dates in your server-side script *without* submitting/refreshing the page.

Here's how you could set it up in one file:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title Here</title>
    <link rel='shortcut icon' href='favicon.ico'>
    <!-- include stylesheet for jquery ui -->
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <?php
      //check if the dates have been posted
      //assign the dates to variables if they've been posted,
      //otherwise assign them the value of false
      $dateDebut = isset($_POST['from'])?$_POST['from']:false;
      $dateFin = isset($_POST['to'])?$_POST['to']:false;
    ?>

    <!-- the form which contains our datepickers -->
    <form action='./' method='POST'>
      <label for='from'>Du</label>
      <input name='from' id='from'>
      <label for='to'>Au</label>
      <input name='to' id='to'>
      <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
    </form>

    <?php
      //print the dates if they were posted (if they aren't set to false)
      if(false !== $dateDebut){
        //start date ms timestamp
        echo 'start date timestamp (ms) : '.$dateDebut."<br>";
        //start date formatted
        echo 'start date (date format - mm/dd/yyyy): '.date("m/d/Y", ($dateDebut / 1000))."<br>";
      }
      if(false !== $dateFin){
        //end date timestamp
        echo 'end date timestamp (ms) : '.$dateFin."<br>";
        //end date formatted
        echo 'end date (date format - mm/dd/yyyy): '.date("m/d/Y", ($dateFin / 1000))."<br>";
      }
    ?>
    <!-- include jquery and jquery-ui -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" integrity="sha256-aaODHAgvwQW1bFOGXMeX+pC4PZIPsvn2h1sArYOhgXQ=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-xNjb53/rY+WmG+4L6tTl9m6PpqknWZvRt0rO1SRnJzw=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      //setup datepickers
      $('[name=from]').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1d",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat : '@',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
      });
      $('[name=to]').datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        dateFormat : '@',
        onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
          $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate );
          var currentDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "getDate" );
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your response ! So, for information, my code is already in a form like that : [link]http://pastebin.com/zQ27hcTv :)

Comment: You should have posted all that to begin with. You have two forms. The first has a submit button - the second does not. You need to add a submit button to the second form, and use that - or put all elements in one form.